# Youtube API - Subscribing to Push Notifications

Tags: xml, push-notification, youtube-api, websub

My final goal is to set up a Webhook whenever a YouTube user uploads a video. After some research I got to [this article](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

But when I get to the part `https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID`, I got `Restricted topic` error when trying the subscribe to the Google/SuperFeedr hubs. I also got my callback URL working.

The topic I want to subscribe to is this: `https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UC7T8roVtC_3afWKTOGtLlBA`

Which shows nothing upon visiting via a browser.

Am I doing something wrong? I've been struggling for a few hours now, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I found [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/339idg/youtube_just_dropped_its_support_for_rssatom_feeds/), but those feeds doesn't have the `rel=”hub”` attribute, so probably useless if I want to subscribe it to hub.

Comment: Not sure why Google points to a superfeedr hub, because... well, they don't ping us! However, you should get data from their hub.

Comment: Same issue here. It also took me long time to realise that `https://www.youtube.com/XML/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=` url were different from `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" ...>` given in youtube channel page source code

Comment: Did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: Has anyone managed to make this work with Youtube API v3? I'm getting the restricted topic as well and no notifcations ...

Comment: Well, I found [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/339idg/youtube_just_dropped_its_support_for_rssatom_feeds/), but that feed doesn't have `rel=”hub”` so it's useless to me. Tried subscribing to that, but never get any notifications. It's really frustrating...

Comment: Really hoping for some help here, I've had the same problem. Someone also has listed here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7138

Comment: See also the discussion here (no answers given though): https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5602

Comment: I was the one that created [issue 7138](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7138), hope they answer us soon.

Comment: It has been fixed : https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7138#c15

Comment: Worked for me using the `https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=CHANNEL_ID` format now (subscriber diagnostics at https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe didn't work though..).

Answer (score 9):

1. you need to send request to subscribe a channel
2. a callback that varifies the subscription request and get actual data on update

subscribe function:

**subscribe.php** may look like:

```php
<?php

function subscribeYoutubeChannel($channel_id = null, $subscribe = true) {
    $subscribe_url = 'https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe';
    $topic_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id={CHANNEL_ID}';
    $callback_url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . str_replace(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . 'youtube_subscribe_callback.php';

    $data = array(
        'hub.mode' => $subscribe ? 'subscribe' : 'unsubscribe',
        'hub.callback' => $callback_url,
        'hub.lease_seconds'=>60*60*24*365,
        'hub.topic'=> str_replace(array(
            '{CHANNEL_ID}'
        ), array(
            $channel_id
        ), $topic_url)
    );

    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    @file_get_contents($subscribe_url, false, $context);

    return preg_match('200', $http_response_header[0]) === 1;
}
```

after the request is sent, the pusub service will call youtube_subscribe_callback.php to verify the subscription
it will use the GET method and it expects to receive an answer which is "hub_challenge".
after that if you upload a video to your test channel youtube_subscribe_callback.php will receive POST request with data.

so **youtube_subscribe_callback.php** (defined in subscribeYoutubeChannel function) may look like:

```php
 <?php
    if (isset($_GET['hub_challenge'])) {
        echo $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    } else {
    
        $video = parseYoutubeUpdate(file_get_contents('php://input'));
        
    }
    
    function parseYoutubeUpdate($data) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $video_id = substr((string)$xml->entry->id, 9);
        $channel_id = substr((string)$xml->entry->author->uri, 32);
        $published = (string)$xml->entry->published;
    
        return array(
            'video_id'=>$video_id,
            'channel_id'=>$channel_id,
            'published'=>$published
        );
    }
```

Comment: It's 'hub.challenge' not 'hub_challenge' (at least now it is). Also, maybe useful for someone to know specifically that this value for 'hub.challenge' is passed as a query param (not in headers or body) when the callback URL is hit after the subscription request.

Comment: Do you know if there is a limit in the number of channels I can subscribe to? I am thinking about using this as the primary way to get a channel update, but for hundreds of thousands of channels.

Comment: @timraybould PHP will replace dot with underscore in $_GET, so 'hub_challenge' is correct here.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to subscribe channel by id, but was able to do it by username:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=username
```

So, you go to this page:

```
https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe
```

Insert your callback URL, RSS feed from youtube with username, and mode "subscribe".

Don't forget to reply from your callback URL, so it can confirm subscription, in PHP just print:

```php
echo $_REQUEST["hub_challenge"];
```

More details [here](http://indiewebcamp.com/How_to_publish_and_consume_PubSubHubbub#How_to_Subscribe) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications).

Comment: BTW, I've subscribed yesterday through pubsubhubbub one of news channels on youtube, and never get ping back to my callback url. So, I'm not sure if this works for youtube RSS feeds.

Answer (score 3):

The process is usually two steps, first you go to the [subscribe](https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/subscribe) page, input your callback server url, topic url (which is basically the feed url for the ytb channel you want to listen to, the other fields are optional), the pub server will verify your subscription with a `GET` request to your callback server, in go it can look like this:

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    challenge := r.URL.Query().Get("hub.challenge")
    if challenge != "" {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, challenge)
    }
})
```

Then on every new video (or title, desc of an old video is updated), the pub will submit a `POST` request to your server with an `xml` in the body looking similar to this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <link rel="hub" href="https://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com" />
  <link rel="self" href="https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCtEorrVfo4GQsN82HsrnKyk" />
  <title>YouTube video feed</title>
  <updated>2018-12-12T06:02:55.950497732+00:00</updated>
  <entry>
    <id>yt:video:_em_FFNUcvs</id>
    <yt:videoId>_em_FFNUcvs</yt:videoId>
    <yt:channelId>UCtEorrVfo4GQsN82HsrnKyk</yt:channelId>
    <title>December 12, 20</title>
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_em_FFNUcvs" />
    <author>
      <name>Ak Ram</name>
      <uri>https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtEorrVfo4GQsN82HsrnKyk</uri>
    </author>
    <published>2018-12-12T05:57:07+00:00</published>
    <updated>2018-12-12T06:02:55.950497732+00:00</updated>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [The guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications)'s url is wrong

`https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml` is not working anymore. but without `/xml` then is working.

There is a sample.

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCJHiO2Dfao-qpYiA79swtAA
https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCJHiO2Dfao-qpYiA79swtAA