# How can I get the status of a user's stream?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm building a thing that tells people when a YouTube stream goes live. In order to build this, I need to *know* when a stream goes live, be it via push notification, polling, or some other method.

With Twitch, it's [dead easy](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/streams.md). All you have to do is send a GET to https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/[STREAMER_USERNAME_HERE] and you get a JSON object with everything you'd ever hope to know (try it in your browser, it's great). I have combed through the YouTube Streaming and Data API's and nothing even close to this feature seems to exist.

I know that something, somewhere is alerting something when a stream goes live, because my phone gets a notification when the people I am subscribed to start streaming. But if there are no public calls in the API, I'm left with no other option than scraping the HTML off a page every couple seconds, which is bad for both me and YouTube.

Further on this, YouTube's [push notification API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) for regular videos famously doesn't work [[1]](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7138) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611459/youtube-api-subscribing-to-push-notifications) [[3]](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2015/04/youtube-has-finally-destroyed-their-rss-feeds/) [[4]](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5602), and every dev is left to either use the deprecated XML feeds (which update sometimes up to an hour slow) or scrape HTML off youtube.com pages (the *only* current solution for instant updates). So, even if there's something off the API that I missed, it's moot if it doesn't actually work.

That said, am I missing something? Is it possible to get a notification if a stream goes live? It's kind of a deal-breaker for YouTube vs Twitch if there isn't.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454238/how-to-check-if-channel-is-streaming-right-now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to do what you are asking with the public YouTube API.

You can only retrieve information about **your own** `liveStream` or `liveBroadcast` objects, not anyone else's.  Additionally, there is no public API to get a notification when another user goes live.